# Was the "Earthrise" witnessed by Apollo 8 the first available "full" photo of the Earth?

Tags: history, photography, earth

Was the video/photos taken during the earth-rise on the Apollo 8 flight the first "blue marble"-esque photo? I've heard the image equated to the "earth's first selfie" and question the technical accuracy of that premise.

[image: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a8/NASA-Apollo8-Dec24-Earthrise.jpg]

*Note to pedants:

Seeing other similar type questions on the site, please understand the *concept* of what I'm asking, if not the accuracy. Yes, you can only take, at best, a photo of only half the earth at a given time, and yes, during Apollo 8 the Earth was partially in shadow....

Comment: those people are "pedants" ;)

Comment: damn autocorrect!! @Hobbes

Comment: Hmmm, pedantic? That doesn't seem like the best fit. Perhaps _donnish_ is better.

Comment: Russel's answer is excellent, but it still is customary to wait 24 hours before clicking the accept checkmark, so other people (no, not me) have a chance to post answers.

Comment: sorry @DrSheldon - new to this particular stack. Although, if a different answer came up that was more accurate, I could simply change the approval

Comment: as an aside - I love questions like this - they always result in lots of interesting and pretty images.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

No; the first full views of Earth from high-altitude satellites predate Apollo 8 by at least two years.

T[his web page has a nice progression of pictures](http://www.donaldedavis.com/2003NEW/NEWSTUFF/DDEARTH.html) of Earth from space from 1959 on.

A Soviet satellite (possibly Molniya-1-3) took this crude picture on May 30, 1966:

[image]

[DODGE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DODGE_(satellite)) took this picture in [September of 1967](http://cosmic-watch.com/first-color-image-of-the-full-illuminated-earth-in-1967/); this is believed to be the first full-color, full-Earth picture:

[image]

[ATS-III](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATS-3) sent this photo in [November of 1967](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-2244450/First-complete-colour-picture-Earth-sale-week.html), which famously became the cover image for the first edition of the [Whole Earth Catalog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whole_Earth_Catalog) (Apollo 8's much prettier Earthrise photo adorned later editions):

[image]

Comment: The Whole Earth Catalog invented the internet before Al Gore did https://i.stack.imgur.com/30aHe.jpg This was a great book for certain "sitting rooms".

Comment: What part of Earth is depicted in the first photo? I have a hard time identifying any continents or oceans on it.

Comment: @d-b Most likely the contrast is mostly cloud versus surface, not land versus water (squint at the other pictures to see what I mean). Assuming it’s in a Molniya orbit and near apogee, I’d expect it to be over the middle of greater Russia, but I don’t know which way the image is oriented.

Comment: fyi I've just asked [What are damper booms and how did they "get out of DODGE"?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/32434/12102)

Comment: That first one looks more like a distorted screaming face than it does the Earth...

Comment: @d-b somehow it looks like the Indian ocean, with India on the top right and Africa on the left. But I could be imagining this.

Comment: It's south up.  Turn it upside down and you'll be looking at South America with Africa on the right and Central America at the top left

Comment: @DaveGremlin That’s a mighty narrow Atlantic.

Comment: @Russell Borogrove You can see a similar view from DSCOVR taken this morning.  Similar longitude but a lower latitude.  Go to https://epic.gsfc.nasa.gov/ and find epic_1b_20181130152859

Answer (score 21):

Although not a blue marble as it's in black and white, [Lunar Orbiter 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_Orbiter_1) took an earlier Earthrise photo on August 23, 1966.  This is the first picture of the Earth from Lunar orbit.

[image: Lunar Orbiter 1 picture of the Earth from the Moon, taken Aug. 23, 1966]

In 2008, the [Lunar Orbiter Image Recovery Project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_Orbiter_Image_Recovery_Project) produced a higher-quality version of this image by reanalyzing the original data.

[image: Lunar Orbiter 1 picture of the Earth from the Moon, taken Aug. 23, 1966, restored by LOIRP]

Lunar Orbiter 1 also took a second Earthrise picture on Aug. 25, 1966 (restored version shown.)

[image: Lunar Orbiter 1 picture of the Earth from the Moon, taken Aug. 25, 1966, restored by LOIRP]

Comment: Thank you so much for this. This is the first time I heard of LOIRP and the restored images quite literally made me shudder and get goosebumps... it is **amazing** to see the high-res images and to realise that Nancy Evans's decision rescued this treasure of data. This for me ranks with the [Prokudin-Gorsky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sergey_Prokudin-Gorsky) image bank.