# Who gave the famous photograph "Earthrise" its name?

Tags: photography, apollo-8

"Earthrise" is one of the most famous photographs in history.  The picture of the Earth from orbit around the moon was taken by astronaut Bill Anders during Apollo 8.  But who gave the picture its iconic name?

[image: Earthrise]

Related: [Was the "Earthrise" witnessed by Apollo 8 the first available "full" photo of the Earth?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/32422/26446)

Answer (score 4):

I believe the photo essentially received that name by acclamation. Before it came to be regarded as the name of the photo, it was the most natural, obvious, and succinct *description* of the contents of the photo. I recall seeing that photo in books and magazines with captions like "Earthrise as seen from Apollo 8." My sense is the word's evolution from description to name was a gradual process.

Comment: Moonrise and sunrise was used before, earthrise was short and very easy to understand.